# How do I add typescript types to a javascript library?

Tags: typescript, types, module

I installed p5 and @types/p5 in my project and import p5 like this:

```
import * as p5 from 'p5'
```

When I use p5.createImage(100, 100) I get this error even though it's definitely a function from p5:

```
Property 'createImage' does not exist on type 'typeof import("D:/dev/repositories/Jeff/node_modules/@types/p5/index.d.ts")'
```

I also get no hints for the p5-methods, so I guess I set it up wrong and need to use maybe a namespace or module-declaration. I tried several things but just can't get I right; Can anyone help me pls?

You might want to look at my setup: https://github.com/Septias/Carcasonne-Online/blob/master/src/pages/PeaceBuilder.vue

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look into the [type file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/p5/global.d.ts), you can see that `createImage` is defined as a `global` variable.

Instead of doing `p5.createImage(100, 100)`, do `createImage(100, 100)`.

Also update your `tsconfig.json` to register the type file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": ["p5"]
  }
}
```

Comment: when I use createImage(100, 100) I get  " 'createImage' is not defined"

Comment: Yes, maybe because my import is falsy?

Comment: Or may be because typescript is anaware of the file type. I updated my answer

Comment: Adding p5 to types sadly didn't solve the issue :/ I linked the git repo in my question if you want to take a look at it